# How can I compare mouse coordinates to values in a custom array in java?

Tags: java

I've made a tile grid (with images) that is 10/10 and I'm able to find where each tile is in the 2d array by hovering my mouse over it. My issue is trying to compare that value (mouse position) and the values/positions in my 2d array.

This is my tile class

```
Tiles [][] grid = new Tiles [10][10];
int mousexpos = mouseX / 100;
  int mouseypos = mouseY / 100;
  int row;


class Tiles {
  String name;
  int type;
  boolean isVisible;
  
  Tiles (String n, int t) {
    this.name = n;
    this.type = t;
    isVisible = true;
  }

  void render(int x, int y) {
    if (this.isVisible) {
      image(pics[this.type], x*100, y*100, 100, 100);
    }
  }
}//Class tiles
```

This is my attempt at getting this to work. "Row" was just something i was experimenting with parsing and mousexpos/mouseypos is just mouseX /100 & mouseY /100 to show where in the array the tile is.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //row = Integer.parseInt("grid[i]", 1);
        println(row);
      for (int j= 0; j <10; j++) {
        if(mousexpos == grid[i] && mouseypos == grid[j]){
          
        }
      }
    }
```

The whole code all in one

```
PImage [] pics = new PImage[5];

Tiles [][] grid = new Tiles [10][10];
int mousexpos = mouseX / 100;
  int mouseypos = mouseY / 100;
  int row;


class Tiles {
  String name;
  int type;
  boolean isVisible;
  
  Tiles (String n, int t) {
    this.name = n;
    this.type = t;
    isVisible = true;
  }

  void render(int x, int y) {
    if (this.isVisible) {
      image(pics[this.type], x*100, y*100, 100, 100);
    }
  }
}//Class tiles

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
    pics[i] = loadImage("tileSet"+i+"ground.png");
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j= 0; j <10; j++) {
      grid[i][j] = new Tiles ("Tilly", 4 );
      //floor(random(pics.length))
    }
  }

//There has got to be a better way to do this
grid[1][0] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[1][1] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[1][2] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[2][2] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[3][2] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[3][3] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[3][4] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[2][5] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[3][5] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[1][5] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[1][6] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[1][7] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[1][8] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[2][8] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[3][8] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[4][8] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[5][8] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[5][7] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[5][6] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[5][5] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[5][4] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[5][3] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[5][2] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[5][1] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[6][1] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[7][1] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[8][1] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[8][2] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[8][3] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[7][3] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[7][4] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[7][5] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[8][5] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[8][6] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[8][7] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[8][8] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);
grid[8][9] = new Tiles ("Tilly" , 2);


}//setup

    void draw() {
background(181,101,29);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (int j= 0; j <10; j++) {
        grid[i][j].render(i,j);
      }
    }
  

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //row = Integer.parseInt("grid[i]", 1);
        println(row);
      for (int j= 0; j <10; j++) {
        if(mousexpos == grid[i] && mouseypos == grid[j]){
          
        }
      }
    }

}//draw end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you are using Processing, fantastic! BUT: please do not post your code as images. Rather post it as a codeblock in the editor so the community can analyse and reproduce the errors. After that I would be happy to help you out! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Sorry about that I will change it to code!

Comment: Grid is a 2D array. So grid[i] is a 1D array. You can access the values contained within grid with two indexes. Eg. `grid[i][j]` but what do you want to compare the value to?

Comment: That looks better, do you mind adding your Main File with `setup()` and `draw()` method? What is your goal with this, what should happen when the mouse is over a tile?

Comment: Not really understanding your question. If each tile is 100 x 100 then you divide the mouseX by 100 to get the column and the mouseY to get the row. Once you have the row/column you can access the grid array to get the tile.

Comment: @matt I want to compare the values to where the mouse is, end goal is to have each tile reveal itself/render when you hover over it, hence the "isVisible" boolean.

Comment: Right, but what's the issue? If you know what tile you're over then in theory you can do things with that tile?

Comment: The issue is that when I directly try and compare the values in the 2d array to my mouse positions it gives me the error "Incompatible operand types tiles_vs.Tiles and int"

Comment: I think something that might make this more clear is that im trying to compare the mousex/y to the positions in the array not the contents. I understand now that what im trying to do isnt working because Im trying to compare an int to pretty much a file. But what I want to do is compare the int to the position said file is in the array and im not sure how.

Comment: The *content* of the grid is tiles. In `draw` you're comparing an int to the *content* of `grid[i]` and `grid[j]`, but ints aren't what's in either of those. AFAICT you're looking at this backwards: you have x/y, the tile at x/y is `grid[x][y]`. Retrieve the tile and do whatever it is you need to do w/ it.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback everyone! I have finally gotten it to work I was overthinking it way too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(grid[mousexpos][mouseypos].isVisible != true){
          grid[mousexpos][mouseypos].isVisible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Consider adding further details to explain what the issue is and/or what your solution does.